# Is the question wrong or have I made a mistake?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Today I saw a question which was asked by a friend in a forum like this.

> Assume $f(x),g(x) \in C^\infty(\Bbb{R}) $. How to construct a function $h(x) \in  C^\infty(\Bbb{R})$, such that 
>   $$h(x)=\begin{cases}f(x) & x \in (-1,1)\\g(x) & x \in \Bbb{R} \setminus (-1,1)\end{cases}$$

But if I set $f(x)\equiv1$ and $g(x)\equiv0$, then $h(x)$ becomes $$h(x)=\begin{cases}1 & x \in (-1,1)\\0 & x \in \Bbb{R} \setminus (-1,1)\end{cases}$$

This function is not continuous at $-1$ and $1$. Have I made a mistake or is the question wrong? Thanks very much.

Comment: In general you need some "space" to get a smooth transition of one function to the other. In that case it is not even possible to have a continuous  function $h$ with such a property. However, it suffices to demand $h(x)=g(x)$ on $\mathbb{R}\backslash (-1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon)$ for every $\epsilon>0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is wrong; a better question would replace the bottom $(-1,1)$ with $(-2,2)$.

Answer (score 1):

To complement the answer above, You can construct a sequence of $C^\infty$ functions which converges to $h(x)$ almost everywhere, I think.